# How can I select a table row with a single click using a custom TableCellEditor?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection, tablecelleditor

I have a `JTable` with a custom `TableCellRenderer` and a custom `TableCellEditor`. By default, the first click on a table row switch from *renderer* to *editor* and the second click *select* the row.

Is there any way I can make the row selected on a **single** click (and swith to the editor)?

I have tried to use:

```
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
```

in my `getTableCellEditorComponent` but it doesn't work, and if I add it to my `getTableCellRendererComponent` it works, but only sometimes.

Here is a full example:

```
public class SelectRowDemo extends JFrame {

    public SelectRowDemo() {
        CellRendererAndEditor rendererAndEditor = new CellRendererAndEditor();
        StringTableModel model = new StringTableModel();
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setDefaultEditor(String.class, rendererAndEditor);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, rendererAndEditor);

        model.addElement("");
        model.addElement("");
        model.addElement("");

        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                new SelectRowDemo();
            }

        });
    }

    class CellRendererAndEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {

        private final JLabel renderer = new JLabel();
        private final JLabel editor = new JLabel();

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return editor.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

            String str = "renderer ";
            str += (isSelected) ? "selected" : "not selected";

            renderer.setText(str);
            return renderer;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

            table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);

            String str = "editor ";
            str += (isSelected) ? "selected" : "not selected";

            editor.setText(str);
            return editor;
        }

    }

    class StringTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private final List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            return data.get(row);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
            if(aValue instanceof String) {
                data.set(row, (String)aValue);
                fireTableRowsUpdated(row, column);
            } else throw new IllegalStateException("aValue is not a String");
        }

        public void addElement(String s) {
            data.add(s);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: are you tried `XxxCellEditor#setClickCountToStart()`

Comment: You should not be trying to change the selection model (or any property of the table) in the editor. The editor is for editing.

Comment: @mKorbel: that method isn't relevant.

Comment: I don't understand the end goal of this question. Is it a curiosity? If the editor is invoked, then obviously the row has been selected. Why can't the editor assume this? The purpose of the editor is to allow the user to enter new data and then save the data in the model. Is the data being saved properly? If you are trying to do some kind of validation of the data based on the row then I would guess this should be done in the stop editing method of the editor at which time I would guess the selected row is available.

Comment: I am facing this exact issue. Does anyone has any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that the table UI is starting to edit the cell before changing selection. If you put a println in getTableCellEditor() and shouldSelectCell(), the editor gets called first, with isSelected == false, then it calls shouldSelectCell and changes the selection.

You can see exactly where it happens in BasicTableUI.adjustSelection(MouseEvent).

```
  boolean dragEnabled = table.getDragEnabled();

            if (!dragEnabled && !isFileList && table.editCellAt(pressedRow, pressedCol, e)) {
                setDispatchComponent(e);
                repostEvent(e);
            }

            CellEditor editor = table.getCellEditor();
            if (dragEnabled || editor == null || editor.shouldSelectCell(e)) {
                table.changeSelection(pressedRow, pressedCol, 
                        BasicGraphicsUtils.isMenuShortcutKeyDown(e), 
                        e.isShiftDown());
            }
```

As for rendering purposes, I'd just render it as if selected == true, since it will before that event is finished processing.

Comment: I am unable to follow the advice. Can you please explain in detail, what do I have to do to counter this issue. I've both editor and renderer for a cell.